# Eslint: how to handle no-use-before-define for dependent functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have 2 dependent functions that call each others, so one or the other has to be declared first which fires an eslint `no-use-before-define` error. I know I can disable the rule but is there any better way do do this?

Simplified example:

```
const a = number => {
  if (number === 0) {
    return b(number);
  }
  
  c(number);
}

const b = number => a(number + 1);

a(0);
```

I can't merge `a` and `b` as they both need to be called separately somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Just use `function` declaration and hoisting takes care of all issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use callback or higher order functions. Hope that will help.
Plz try this code and leme know if it works fine with your linting rules.

```js
const a = (number, call) => {
  if (number === 0) {
    return call(number);
  }
  c(number);
}

const b = number => a(number + 1, b);

const c = number => console.log(1);

a(0, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use array destructuring combined with IIFE to define both functions simultaneously:

```
const [a, b] = (() => [
  (number) => (number === 0 ? b(number) : c(number)),
  (number) => a(number + 1),
])();

a(0);
```

Also works with object destructuring if you prefer named components:

```
const { a, b } = (() => ({
  a: (number) => (number === 0 ? b(number) : c(number)),
  b: (number) => a(number + 1),
}))();

a(0);
```